# Laravel: Custom login redirects to /home instead of a /welcome page

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a custom login. After login, it lands to '/home' page instead of '/welcome' page.

Here is my Login Controller :

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/welcome';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function view()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'email'    => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);

        $loginValue = $request->input('email');

        $login_type = $this->getLoginType($loginValue);

        $request->merge([
            $login_type => $loginValue
        ]);

        if (auth()->attempt($request->only($login_type, 'password'))) {
            // return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
            return redirect()->intended(route('welcome'));
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors([ 'email' => "These credentials do not match our records." ]);
    }

    public function getLoginType($loginValue)
    {
        return filter_var($loginValue, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) ? 'email'
       : ( (preg_match('%^(?:(?:\(?(?:00|\+)([1-4]\d\d|[1-9]\d?)\)?)?[\-\.\ \/]?)?((?:\(?\d{1,}\)?[\-\.\ \/]?){0,})(?:[\-\.\ \/]?(?:#|ext\.?|extension|x)[\-\.\ \/]?(\d+))?$%i', $loginValue)) ? 'mobile' : 'name' );
    }
}
```

I have change the redirect path from Illuminate\Foundation\Exception\Handler.php :

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
  return $request->expectsJson() ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401 : redirect('/');
}
```

My routes file:

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@view')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

Comment: Do you want to show the `welcome` view?

Comment: @Zain Farooq, yes.

Comment: Change `protected $redirectTo = '/welcome';` to other route you want

Comment: @Ivan, changed the redirection to another page. Redirect back to home

Comment: where your 'welcome` url points ?

Comment: can you share the `Routes` of it.?

Comment: @Dhaval Purohit, Change the url to '/admin'

Route::get('/admin', 'Auth\LoginController@welcome')->name('admin');

In Login Controller: public function welcome() {  return view('/admin');  }

Comment: okay and is it the same login controller as posted above.

Comment: and have you assigned the middleware to route.? The `auth` `middleware` to `admin` route.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit, yes..it is

Comment: @DhavalPurohit, you mean to assign middleware('auth') to admin route? If it is, i tried that too

Comment: Because if you redirect to admin which call the welcome in logincontroller.it might be visible as guest.

Comment: @DhavalPurohit, solved the problem by putting the "index method" in another controller! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to redirect to "/Welcome" page. You should require changes in a middleware.

Middleware: RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

Following changes needed.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/welcome');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

change return redirect to "/welcome" instead of "/home".

I hope this solution can be help to solve your problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Hey, don't needed to change the Middleware. I have simply created another controller and define a method and add that to routes file. and, that worked for me! Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

In Larave 8.0,

Modify the public const HOME as '/' instead of '/Home' in app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php

Answer (score 0):

change this `return redirect()->intended(route('welcome'));` to `return redirect(url('/welcome'))` also add route to /welcome in web.php file.

Comment: used return redirect(url('/welcome')) and added route to '/welcome'. Redirect to '/home'

Answer (score 0):

```php
Redirect::intended('welcome');

// Try and redirect them to where they were going, if it fails, redirect them to homepage
```

So I think you have any issue with welcome page route or you are missing that welcome page.

Comment: Routing was okay. Solved the problem by creating another controller and use that route in route file. and that works fine.